# Kettle - connect to MySQL still not working even after adding the MySQL driver

Tags: pdi

Apologies for this post, I am sure that it has been answered numerous time but despite all the reading I have done I am not able to connect the PDI to MySQL.

I am using pdi-6.1.0.1-196-x64, I have downloaded the JDBC connecter http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/, unzipped it and copy the mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar file into /Users/jdrhlik/Downloads/Desktop/DataIntegration/design-tools/data-integration/lib

Then I had re started the PDI. Unfortunately getting still same error. Please see below.

Any help?

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Error connecting to database [AWS MySQL] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database


Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "cbi-solution-instance.caowhklkpbrk.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306"'.




org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database


Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "cbi-solution-instance.caowhklkpbrk.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306"'.


at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:466)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:364)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:335)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:325)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2734)
at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:591)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:43)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:137)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:88)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:55)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:116)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:60)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.step.BaseStepDialog.showDbDialogUnlessCancelledOrValid(BaseStepDialog.java:776)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.step.BaseStepDialog$EditConnectionListener.widgetSelected(BaseStepDialog.java:1393)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.sql.ExecSQLDialog.open(ExecSQLDialog.java:598)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonStepsDelegate.editStep(SpoonStepsDelegate.java:125)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.editStep(Spoon.java:8783)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.editStep(TransGraph.java:3072)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.mouseDoubleClick(TransGraph.java:755)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1347)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7989)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9269)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:662)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error connecting to database: (using class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver)
Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "cbi-solution-instance.caowhklkpbrk.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306"'.


at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:579)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:450)
... 64 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "cbi-solution-instance.caowhklkpbrk.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306"'.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:917)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:336)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:561)
... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "cbi-solution-instance.caowhklkpbrk.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.port(NonRegisteringDriver.java:823)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
... 68 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the version number and bin extension from the JDBC driver (at least that did the trick for me).

`cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar /Users/jdrhlik/Downloads/Desktop/DataIntegration/design-tools/data-integration/lib/mysql-connector-java.jar`